# Are these spinach leaves safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, spinach

I bought a bag of spinach late at night and left it in the balcony for the night (the weather was cold enough). In the morning I forgot to take them in and to my wonder the sun was out and shining! Some of the leaves changed color like the ones in the picture. Are they safe to eat? They are not soggy or anything, just the color change!
[image]

Comment: I've eaten leaves like that and they were fine. I'll leave the answering to someone who knows for sure, but my guess is they've just broken down a little, like what happens when you cook them.

Comment: The actual temperature outside is an important detail, both overnight and during the day. Whether the spinach is safe to eat depends on if it ever entered the danger zone (between 4–60°C or 40–140°F) and, if so, how long it was there for.

Comment: @abion47-- it must have been around 8-10° C, for 10 hours I think.